# Attaching a locally uploaded VHD to a Classic Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I have a VHD I uploaded to Azure using the

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent
```

and attempted using the -

```
Add-AzureVhd
```

When I utilize the

```
Add-AzureDataDisk
```

in the console, the VHD appears to be attached to LUN 0 on the VM, when I utilize
Get-AzureVM I utilized the appropriate URI for the MediaLocation argument, but when I check the Classic Portal (Web Interface) or go into the VM itself, the VHD is still not attached.

If I do the process manually, the VHD attaches all fine and dandy. Under 
    VMs->Instances->Disks

I can see the VHD thats been uploaded there if I do the process manually, but utilizing cmdlets, I cannot seem to get the VHD to appear in "existing disks"  via VM instances.

Now I have triple checked everything, my storage account is in the same region as my VM instance. My locally uploaded VHD is fixed and labeled correctly in blobs as "someVHD.vhd", when I attempt to use Add-AzureDataDisk, in the console it returns that the disk is attached, the weird behavior is that if I labelled the existing disk during the attach cmdlet arguments, the disk still does not attach utilizing cmdlets.

This is my exact script -

```
    $createVHD = New-VHD -Path $($vhdInstallFullPath) -Fixed -SizeBytes 256MB -ComputerName $hostName

    Copy files to VHD and prepare them for upload to azure utilizing either Set-AzureStorageBlobContent or Add-AzureVHD, in this case I utilized Set-AzureStorageBlobContent, because the VHD is really small.

    $migrateVHD = Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $vhdInstallFullPath -Blob $VHDInstallName -Container $StorageContainerName -Context $($newAzureContext.Context) -BlobType Page -Confirm:$False

    $addAzureDataDisk = Add-AzureDataDisk -VM $azureVMInfo -ImportFrom -MediaLocation $azureInstallBlobURI -DiskLabel "InstallPackage" -LUN $azureDataDiskLUN
```

Now I have a lot of variables and I'm doing a lot of other things to get the storage context, the Azure VM object, and copying files to the vhd before I uplaod, but that script block should give everyone my gist.

Could my issue possibly be between utilizing page blobs over block blobs for the VHD? From documentation I understood that a VHD with multiple files would want to be a page blob.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use the following cmdlet.

```
Get-AzureVM "stlcs01" -Name "shuitest1" | Add-AzureDataDisk -ImportFrom -MediaLocation  "https://t5portalvhdsx2463gvmvrz7.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/shui-shui-2017-02-02.vhd"   -DiskLabel "InstallPackage" -LUN 1
```

I find a good article about your problem, maybe you could check this article:[Add, Import Data Disk to Azure Virtual Machine using Powershell](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2016/01/14/add-import-data-disk-to-azure-virtual-machine-using-powershell/).

I test in my lab.

```
Add-AzureVhd -Destination “https://t5portalvhdsx2463gvmvrz7.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/shui.vhd” -LocalFilePath “D:\shui.vhd” -NumberOfUploaderThreads 32

Get-AzureVM -name shuitest -ServiceName shuitest | Add-AzureDataDisk -ImportFrom -MediaLocation “https://t5portalvhdsx2463gvmvrz7.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/shui.vhd” -DiskLabel “test” -LUN 1

Get-AzureVM -ServiceName shuitest -Name shuitest|Get-AzureDataDisk
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that countless times and when I utilize Update-AzureVM, I return null on the AccountName parameter, I ensure that I'm logged in and everything is correct, but I throw a null value error. At the time I run that cmdlet while piping the VM object to Add-AzureDataDIsk, it still causes errors in the consoel as well from piping Get-AzureVM to Add-AzureDataDisk.

Going to utilize the link you sent and see if that works! THanks

Comment: @camerajunkie I had test in my lab, you could not add parameter `Update-AzureVM`

Comment: I did, but it wasn't completely in the way you outlined the steps, when I get a chance will update to solved with the solution.